# C++ if, else if, else statement is not printing cout result

Tags: c++, if-statement, char, cin

I'm struggling with this code. Been working at these if, else if, else statements for a few hours now.

```
void metric()
{
    double mWeight;
    double mHeight;
    double mAge;
    char mExercise;
    bool mCorrectExercise = true;
    int metricResult;

    cout << "Please type in your age: ";
    cin >> mAge;

    cout << "Please type in your weight: ";
    cin >> mWeight;

    cout << "Please type in your height: ";
    cin >> mHeight;

    cout << "Finally, please select an exercise program that most closely matches yours.\n\n1) No exercise.\n\n2) 1-2 hours a week.\n\n3) 3-5hours a week.\n\n4) 6-10 hours a week\n\n5) 11-20 hours a week.\n\n6) 20+ hours a week.\n\n";
    cin >> mExercise;


    if (mExercise == 1)
    {
        metricResult = (mWeight * 11) + (mHeight * 8) - (mAge * 6.5) + 66;
        cout << metricResult << "\n\n";
    }
    else if (mExercise == 2)
    {
        metricResult = (mWeight * 11) + (mHeight * 8) - (mAge * 6.5) + 66;
        cout << metricResult * 1.1 << "\n\n";
    }
    else if (mExercise == 3)
    {
        metricResult = (mWeight * 11) + (mHeight * 8) - (mAge * 6.5) + 66;
        cout << metricResult * 1.25 << "\n\n";
    }
    else if (mExercise == 4)
    {
        metricResult = (mWeight * 11) + (mHeight * 8) - (mAge * 6.5) + 66;
        cout << metricResult * 1.35 << "\n\n";
    }
    else if (mExercise == 5)
    {
        metricResult = (mWeight * 11) + (mHeight * 8) - (mAge * 6.5) + 66;
        cout << metricResult * 1.5 << "\n\n";
    }
    else if (mExercise == 6)
    {
        metricResult = (mWeight * 11) + (mHeight * 8) - (mAge * 6.5) + 66;
        cout << metricResult * 1.7 << "\n\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Invalid input. Please try again.\n\n";
    }
}
```

They aren't successfully printing the `cout` results. I had it somewhat working earlier when the math formulas inside the statements used to be different. I've tried to have all of them as `if` statements which I'm pretty sure isn't how it's supposed to be. I also had an issue where it would only print the result from option #**1** despite typing in any other option.

TLDR, with the current code, simply won't print no matter which option I pick from **1** to **6**.

Comment: `char mExercise` is a reason why the results won't be equal to 1-6. The ASCII value the character '1' is 49, for example, not (int) 1. Maybe you want to use `int mExercise` instead.

Comment: `mExercise` has type `char`.   When the input is `1`, the value of `mExercise` read from `std::cin` is `'1'` (note the single-quotes) but the `char` with value `'1'` does not have a numeric value of `1`.   To fix, either (1) change the type of `mExercise` to be `int` (so reading input of `1` will do the translation, and give a numeric value of `1` rather than a `char` with value `'1'`) or (2) change the comparisons in `if` statements to `mExercise == '1'` (and similarly for other values).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add single quotation marks (i.e. `''`) to your values. For instance, this `'1'` is a character literal but this `1` is not a character literal (it's an integer literal). You need to compare a value of `char` type with values of `char` type.

Also, you better use a switch statement instead of the `if else if` structure.

Like this:

```
#include <iostream>


void metric( )
{
    // bool mCorrectExercise = true;

    std::cout << "Please type in your age: ";
    double mAge;
    std::cin >> mAge;

    std::cout << "Please type in your weight: ";
    double mWeight;
    std::cin >> mWeight;

    std::cout << "Please type in your height: ";
    double mHeight;
    std::cin >> mHeight;

    std::cout << "Finally, please select an exercise program that "
    "most closely matches yours.\n\n1) No exercise.\n\n"
    "2) 1-2 hours a week.\n\n3) 3-5hours a week.\n\n"
    "4) 6-10 hours a week\n\n5) 11-20 hours a week.\n\n"
    "6) 20+ hours a week.\n\n";

    char mExercise;
    std::cin >> mExercise;

    const double metricResult { (mWeight * 11) + (mHeight * 8) - (mAge * 6.5) + 66 };


    switch ( mExercise )
    {
        case '1':
            std::cout << metricResult * 1.0 << "\n\n";
            break;
        case '2':
            std::cout << metricResult * 1.1 << "\n\n";
            break;
        case '3':
            std::cout << metricResult * 1.25 << "\n\n";
            break;
        case '4':
            std::cout << metricResult * 1.35 << "\n\n";
            break;
        case '5':
            std::cout << metricResult * 1.5 << "\n\n";
            break;
        case '6':
            std::cout << metricResult * 1.7 << "\n\n";
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "Invalid input. Please try again.\n\n";
    }
}

int main( )
{
    metric( );
}
```

It's probably also worth mentioning that due to the changes I made, the assembly output of the program decreased from 207 lines down to 136 lines which means it's more efficient now.

Comment: You could go further of course with a container of metric result coefficients indexed by `mExercise`. Almost a one-liner. And check the return values of `std::cin` too.

Comment: @Bathsheba Yeah that came to my mind too. But then I decided not to do that just to keep the code similar to the OP's code snippet.

Comment: Thanks man! I never used switch statements yet but this helps me understand them better.

Comment: Ah gotcha. Thanks for pointing that out. It's done

Answer (score 2):

It's because of `char mExercise;` and it compiles because char can be compared to int.

Change that line to `int mExercise;` and it will work.

Comment: Oh man, haha this is what happens when I work past my bedtime! Thanks.. I used to have those choices as A, B, C etc and thought that was odd and changed them to numbers and ofc forgot to change the datatype. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

mExcercise is a char, so in conditional statments, if you want to use char, you have to put the  '' outside.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use '' around the values(1,2,etc.) or change mExercise to int.